# How to crop the image data before saving the in gallery?

Tags: android, camera, crop

I am working on camera app using camera API2.
I have a camera preview. 
I can select the area of my interest as you can see.
How ever I want to just take a photo from the area inside the rectangle. 
Does any one know that how to implement this?  If you have gone through any tutorials/sample code please post the links.Thanks in advance

[image: screen shot of my camera app]

Comment: are you able to take a full photo? If you are, then just crop it, and delete original image if required.

Answer (score 0):

When you have done with capturing image then you will get path of caputered image or store bitmap you got in `onActivityResult()` for capture.

Now then use below code to perform cropping that image:

```
public void performCrop(){
    //call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not support it)
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP"); 
    //indicate image type and Uri
cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
    //set crop properties
cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    //indicate aspect of desired crop
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    //indicate output X and Y
cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
    //retrieve data on return
cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(cropIntent,"Cropping"), PIC_CROP);

}
```

Now again inside `onActivityResult()` match your `PIC_CROP` request code and get result image as below:

```
//get the returned data
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
//get the cropped bitmap
Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
```

Comment: this might not work on some (most part?) of devices since `com.android.camera.action.CROP` not a mandatory intent action for all devices, but more likely optional

Comment: Yes, there is possibility that device might don't have any app that can CROP.  so to solve it you need to create your own cropping activity which can do it for you.

Comment: Also, your answer does not quite match the question.

Comment: Check this link :https://gist.github.com/pookie13/1ad1623bec8d7ee76b66 may be it could help.